# Wxpython Filter dropdown not working in latest version 4.1.1 same example working with 4.0.7 version

Tags: python, wxpython

**When assigning the value to combobox in event it will fire again same event and program goes in infinite loop. however same code working in wxpython version 4.0.7. correct me if I am doing something wrong.**

```py
import wx      
    class Mywin(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent: object, title: object) -> object:
            super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 200))
            self.languages = ['C', 'C++', 'Python', 'Java', 'Perl']
    
            panel = wx.Panel(self)
            box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    
            self.label = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Your choice:", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
            box.Add(self.label, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
    
            cblbl = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Combo box", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
            box.Add(cblbl, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
    
            self.combo = wx.ComboBox(panel, choices=self.languages)
            box.Add(self.combo, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
    
            box.AddStretchSpacer()
            self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.oncombo)
            self.ignoreEvtText = False
    
            panel.SetSizer(box)
            self.Centre()
            self.Show()
    
        def oncombo(self, event):
    
            if self.ignoreEvtText:
                self.ignoreEvtText = False
                return
    
            textEntered = event.GetString()
    
            self.label.SetLabel("You selected" + self.combo.GetValue() + " from Combobox" + textEntered)
    
            if textEntered:
                self.ignoreEvtText = True
                matching = [s for s in self.languages if textEntered in s]
                self.combo.Set(matching)
                self.combo.SetInsertionPoint(len(textEntered))
                self.combo.SetValue(textEntered)
            else:
                self.combo.Set(self.languages)
    
            self.combo.Popup()
    
    
    app = wx.App()
    Mywin(None, 'ComboBox and Choice demo')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.oncombo)`

rather than:

`self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.oncombo)`

EVT_TEXT causes you to drop into an continual event loop.

Each time the text changes, if fires the event, which changes the text, which fires the event, which ......

Comment: Yes, I have used self.combo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.oncombo) but functionality won't work as I want, this event work on selection and I want to auto populate list on entered text. is anything around that.

Comment: @Sudarshan Currently it is unclear, to me, what it is that you are trying to achieve with this. As coded you are restricting the initial list options down to the single option you choose. Are you attempting to add in extra options, that are typed in by the user? If that is the case add the `style` `wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` and bind to the event `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER`. If not, edit your question to explain precisely, what you want. Provide an example, before and after.